# Flickering ACS_CKBOARD using ncurses in rxvt

Tags: c, linux, ncurses, rxvt

I wanted to get familiar with the curses interface (never used it before), so I wrote a little *snake* game last weekend. There's a one-line *status* `WINDOW *` and the rest of the screen is the *field* `WINDOW *` The game logic calls a central drawing function to put an item, only when necessary:

```
/* note: CP_* are just enum values to give my own color pairs names */
void
screen_putItem(Screen *self, int y, int x, Item item, int refresh)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case EMPTY:
            mvwaddch(self->field, y, x, ' '|COLOR_PAIR(CP_WHITE));
            break;
        case HEAD:
#ifdef WIN32
            /* 'smiley' character for windows console */
            mvwaddch(self->field, y, x,
                    1|COLOR_PAIR(CP_YELLOW)|A_BOLD|A_ALTCHARSET);
#else
            mvwaddch(self->field, y, x, '@'|COLOR_PAIR(CP_YELLOW)|A_BOLD);
#endif
            break;
        case TAIL:
            mvwaddch(self->field, y, x, ACS_CKBOARD|COLOR_PAIR(CP_YELLOW));
            break;
        case FOOD:
            mvwaddch(self->field, y, x, '#'|COLOR_PAIR(CP_GREEN)|A_BOLD);
            break;
        case FFOOD:
            mvwaddch(self->field, y, x, '#'|COLOR_PAIR(CP_GREEN));
            break;
        case WALL:
            mvwaddch(self->field, y, x,
                    ' '|COLOR_PAIR(CP_RED)|A_REVERSE);
            break;
    }
    if (refresh) wrefresh(self->field);
}
```

Problem is: in `rxvt`, the body of the snake (made from `TAIL` items) is sometimes flickering. It is **not** redrawn on snake movement, only the last position of the head is replaced by a `TAIL` and the tail item at the end of the snake is replaced by an `EMPTY`.

For your reference, the whole project is [on github](https://github.com/Zirias/cursedsnake), see the [revision at time of asking this question](https://github.com/Zirias/cursedsnake/tree/ac898158ee2fa5a8ebddca5d75fe33e0402083f5).

For input, the code uses `getch()` and I already checked this isn't the problem (it shouldn't be, `stdscr` is refreshed at init and never touched again) by using only `wgetch()` on the *field* window with the same result.

Also, it works fine (flicker-free) in good old `xterm` and in the windows console, using *pdcurses*. It works fine in `rxvt` **iff** I replace the `ACS_CKBOARD` in the snippet above with some "ordinary" character.

So, now I'd like to know: Did I encounter a bug/shortcoming in `rxvt`? Is there something special about the `ACS_*` characters that could cause a terminal to flicker? Is there anything just wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1):

[Tracing](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_trace.3x.html) shows me that your program does almost all [wgetch](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html)'s from stdscr, but almost all [refresh](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html)'s are done against the second window created (looks like the first is just a status line).

ncurses' trace feature is normally in a debug-library; the copies that I compile for myself have it compiled in normally.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, thanks a lot for your input! this looks like an interesting feature for debugging. Unfortunately, I already tried a version doing `wgetch()` only on this second window (named *field* in my code) and the result in `rxvt` was the same ... so I ditched this changeset straight to /dev/null ... If it's helpful for debugging, I could recreate it, but I don't think this is the issue here. Nevertheless, +1 for some debugging facility I didn't know about, thanks!